# Open two files. Read from the first file and do lookup on second before writing a line

Tags: python

I have two text files. I can open both with Python successfully.

I open the first file and read a data element into a variable using the for l in file construct.
I open the second file and read a data element into a variable using the for l in file construct.

If both variables match I write data to a text file. For the first line read it works perfectly but subsequent lines do not.  The `FIN` variable never changes even though it finds a new line that starts with `D` further along. Is there a way to loop through two files like this? Am I missing something obvious?

```
File2Split = 'c:\\temp\\datafile\\comparionIP.txt'
GetResident = 'c:\\temp\\datafile\\NPINumbers.txt'


writefile = open('c:\\temp\\datafile\\comparionIPmod.txt','w')
openfile = open(File2Split,'r')
openfileNPI = open(GetResident,'r')

FIN = ''
FirstChar = ''
FIN2 = ''


for l in openfile:
   FirstChar = (l[0:1])
   if FirstChar =='D':
       FIN = (l[21:31])
       #print (FIN)
       if FIN.startswith('1'):
           writefile.write(l)

   elif FirstChar in ['F','G','C','R']:
       writefile.write(l)

   elif FirstChar =='N':
       for l2 in openfileNPI:
           FIN2 = (l2[0:10])
           NPI = ('N' + (l2[11:21]))
           if FIN2 == FIN:
              writefile.write(NPI + '\n')

               

       
openfileNPI.close()
openfile.close()
writefile.close()
```

Comment: For every line in `openfile` that starts with `N`, you read the *entirety* of `openfileNPI`.  Not only is this inefficient (and possibly incorrect based on your description), but the file object acts like an iterator; once you have iterated over its contents, the iterator has been consumed and cannot be read again.  You need to either `openfileNPI.seek(0)`, close and re-open the file, or read the contents of both files into memory *before* operating on the contents.

Comment: Not sure if I got everything, but one thing is obvious: The first time you do `for l2 in openfileNPI:` you consume the whole file. If you enter this part again no more lines will be found.

Comment: I'll check out openfileNPI.seek(0) when I'm back at work tomorrow. I totally get what you and Matthias are saying. I'm a database administrator by trade but was thrown into this out of necessity. 

thanks for the commentary.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Also, it is good practice to handle files using the `with` statement. You can open all three of them at the same time such as `with open(File2Split, 'r') as first_read, open(GetResident, 'r') as second_read, open('file.txt', 'w') as out_file:`

Comment: So, not that anyone care buts I found a novel (to me) solution. The data in the second file is also in a sql server database. To that end I wrote my records from the text and used FIN variable in a sql statement via pyodbc to pull data I wanted into a dictionary and looped through the dictionary to write every row returned from the query to my text file and voila I had the data from the original file and the additional data from the database in a single file grouped by each logical record set. I do want to thank everyone for their consideration in showing me how I was walking the wrong path.